# git history changes after a checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a history that I'm happy with:

```
$ git log --oneline -n60
b1bbe6a JIRA-1569 later fixes
b021112 JIRA-1569 later fixes
0734203 JIRA-1569 adding new statuses
b38c4a2 Merge branch 'feature/MultipleStars' of feature/MultipleStars
0e2bcbd Merge remote-tracking branch 'remotes/origin/feature/AutoStars' into feature/MultipleStars
d8d6be9 JIRA-1520 Removed the datasource reference from web.xml to fix java naming lookup issue
d8085e0 JIRA-1569 fix filter
9641af1 JIRA-1569 displaying MR info
ecb3b3c JIRA-1569 commit
002820d JIRA-1569 include statuses and dates in the response
7b912c8 JIRA-1569 translate SP to ibatis
9de1c77 JIRA-3107 : Put a condition for userid (only for IVR reqeust) to avoid concurrent login session check.
e78716c JIRA-3181 - Mass Reformat and removal of Imports
2907ffc JIRA-3057 Auto accept WS Changes.                <<<<<---HERE!!!!!
212379a JIRA-3057 Auto Accept changes.
2f79bbc JIRA-76 MP Payment Acceptance with fixed Acceptance type
842c02f JIRA-59 Multiple Payee dashboard changes
3552c15 JIRA-3056 Auto Accept Changes in request response
f03d150 Merge pull request #25 in JIRA/My from release/digitalStarts to feature/RealTimeStars
4c9a7d6 JIRA-2274 Added blah, blah in the correct position and rererred the right package name.
288eb2b JIRA-2274 - Update RTP Payments in Transaction Staging
9dfdf7c JIRA-2272, JIRA-51 - Initial commit - Fetch CP RTP value and RTP Routing number Validation
a16ce9a JIRA-2378 - Settings file to build web service
```

But, I do a checkout (which I marked as HERE above):

```
$get checkout 2907ffc
```

And now I get a different history:

```
$ git log --oneline
2907ffc JIRA-3057 Auto accept WS Changes.
212379a JIRA-3057 Auto Accept changes.
3552c15 JIRA-3056 Auto Accept Changes in request response
f03d150 Merge pull request #25 in CQP3/consumer-portal-webservice from release/digitalClearXChangePhase2 to feature/RealTimePayments
4c9a7d6 JIRA-2274 Added blah, blah in the correct position and rererred the right package name.
288eb2b JIRA-2274 - Update RTP Payments in Transaction Staging
```

These 2 commits have disappeared from the history: .

```
2f79bbc JIRA-76 MP Payment Acceptance with fixed Acceptance type
842c02f JIRA-59 Multiple Payee dashboard changes
```

I thought I understood git fairly well, but this has me very confused.

Comment: Try it with `--graph` or use a GUI app to look at the log. Those are probably on different branches.

Answer (score 2):

If a commit has multiple ancestors, you'll see all of them interleaved in the log, ordered by their timestamps.  So I'm guessing you have a situation like this:

```
A --> B --> C ---> D
        \
         -----> E ----> F
```

You were originally at `A`, so your log showed you `A`, `B`, `C`, `E`, `D`, `F`.  You then checked out (say) `C`, so now all you can see is `C` and `D`.

The easiest way to confirm this is to re-run `git log` with the `--graph` flag.